# Problems with .zsh and Pandoc , unexpect "

Tags: markdown, zsh, pandoc

I'm trying to use pandoc 2.5 to convert an .md file to html (among other filetypes I want to render this file to) and I'm finding a problem probably related to the shell I'm using

I'm using Debian, with pandoc 2.5 , and I installed texlive2020.iso , and added its path to my .zsh (I'm using .zsh instead of bash that may be causing the problem)

```sh
pandoc -f markdown -t html notes_linux_jun2020.md -o notes_linux_jun2020.html
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math 'SHELL - Download the other shell you want to install + https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh + sh -c "', rendering as TeX:
  sh/ohmyzsh + sh -c "
                     ^
  unexpected '"'
  expecting "\\bangle", "\\brace", "\\brack", "\\choose", "\\displaystyle", "{", letter, digit, ".", "\\mbox", "\\text", "\\textbf", "\\textit", "\\textrm", "\\textsf", "\\texttt", "\\bm", "\\boldsymbol", "\\mathbb", "\\mathbf", "\\mathbfcal", "\\mathbffrak", "\\mathbfit", "\\mathbfscr", "\\mathbfsfit", "\\mathbfsfup", "\\mathbfup", "\\mathbold", "\\mathcal", "\\mathds", "\\mathfrak", "\\mathit", "\\mathrm", "\\mathscr", "\\mathsf", "\\mathsfit", "\\mathsfup", "\\mathtt", "\\mathup", "\\pmb", "\\symbf", "\\texttt", "\\sqrt", "\\surd", "\\mspace", "\\hspace", "\\mathop", "\\mathrel", "\\mathbin", "\\mathord", "\\mathopen", "\\mathclose", "\\mathpunct", "\\phantom", "\\boxed", "\\overset", "\\stackrel", "\\underset", "\\frac", "\\tfrac", "\\dfrac", "\\binom", "\\genfrac", "\\substack", "_", "^", "\\begin", "\\ensuremath", "\\bigg", "\\Bigg", "\\big", "\\Big", "\\biggr", "\\Biggr", "\\bigr", "\\Bigr", "\\biggl", "\\Biggl", "\\bigl", "\\", "\\left", "\\not", "!", "'", "''", "'''", "''''", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", ":", ":=", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "~", "\\operatorname" or end of input
```

Comment: The shell isn't the problem. The error message suggests a line like `$SHELL - Download ...`, and the `$` signals the beginning of math mode in TeX. The rest of the line is valid (if not typical) mathematical input, until you reach the `"`. I'm not sure why `pandoc` is trying to process anything as TeX, though (is the markdown first converted to TeX, then from TeX to HTML?).

Comment: It should be from .md to .html . I don't need TeX at all. In the .md files there are no formulas , I don't know why is processing is a TeX

Comment: pandoc markdown can contain raw LaTeX... you should 1) update to the newest pandoc version, 2) reduce your input file to a minimal example that still causes the error...